# align View programmatically doesn't work

Tags: android

Here is my layout:

- ScrollView

  - LinearLayout

    - RelativeLayout

      - ImageView
      - TextView
    - RelativeLayout

      - ImageView
      - TextView

and here is my function which create the layouts and views

```
    public void createUI(int count)
    {
        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
        ScrollView.LayoutParams svp = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(
                ScrollView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ScrollView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        scrollView.setLayoutParams(svp);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(llp);

        int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 110, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int ivSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 90, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        {
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);
            relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(rlp);

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setId(R.id.txtImage);
            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myborder));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imagelp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ivSize, ivSize);
            imagelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(imagelp);


            TextView txtName = new TextView(this);
            imageView.setId(R.id.txtName);
            txtName.setText("Abu Baka");
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams namelp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            namelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.txtImage);
            txtName.setLayoutParams(namelp);

            relativeLayout.addView(imageView);
            relativeLayout.addView(txtName);
            linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
        }
        scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
        setContentView(scrollView);
    }
```

I set the imageView id programmatically`imageView.setId(R.id.txtImage);` and set rule to the txtName`namelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.txtImage);`, but it not working. 

Here is my output:

[image]

The word `Abu Baka` suppose to be right of the imageView, but it's not...How to solve this? or is there any wrong with my code?

This is my `ids.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="txtImage" type="id"/>
    <item name="txtName" type="id"/>
    <item name="txtSince" type="id"/>
    <item name="txtComment" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add your child views to its parent, invoke the method with the layout params:

```
relativeLayout.addView(imageView, imageView.getLayoutParams());
relativeLayout.addView(txtName, , txtName.getLayoutParams());
linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout, relativeLayout.getLayoutParams());
```

Be sure that you already set them on the views or add new layout params in addView() method.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done this like below:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams namelp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) txtName.getLayoutParams();
namelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.txtImage);
txtName.setLayoutParams(namelp);
```

Also, you have missed setting the id for `txtName`.

Answer (score 0):

This line worked for me, use

```
namelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, imageView.getId());
```

**instead of**

```
namelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.txtImage);
```

FYI : As I was testing with 2.3 version, made another change (for u not required I guess)

```
imagelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
```